# Is there a way to get the day of month on Android?

Tags: android, date

I have a `Date` value and would like to display the day of the month.  It seems like the `getDays` method returns the day of the week.

Is there a way to get the day of the month?

Answer (score 6):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(yourDateObj);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

OR

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
String day = dateFormat.format(yourDateObj);
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, according to Android Developers [website](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html):

```
This method (getDay()) is deprecated. use `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`
```

Regarding your specific question, the [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) object has a constant named `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` which indicates the ordinal number of the day of the week within the current month.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling getDate() on your date object will return the day of the month.

Comment: this method has deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Just use my method if you have unixTime:

```
public int getDayInt(long unixTime) {
    return Integer.parseInt(DateFormat.format("dd", new Date(unixTime)).toString());
}
```

or if you have a Date:

```
public int getDayInt(Date date) {
    return Integer.parseInt(DateFormat.format("dd", date).toString());
}
```